# Property 'inputs' does not exist on type '{ title: string; buttons:in ionic3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hell to all,
I have call i have dynamically create checkbox and push the KeyId into array but i got above error i have already declared the type but i don't understand got this error?

```js
options.inputs = [];
  //Here we will generate dynamically check-box
  for(let i=0; i< data.subCategoriesDtos.length; i++) {
    this.subCategoryObject  = data.subCategoriesDtos[i];

    options.inputs.push({  
      value: this.subCategoryObject.keyId,
      label: this.subCategoryObject.subCategoryName,
      type: 'checkbox',
      checked: this.showSelectedSubcategory(this.selectedSubcategoryArray[i])
    });
  }
  // Create the alert with the options
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(options);
  alert.present();
```

Comment: Show the `console.log()` of the error..

Comment: sir this error is occur during compile time inside loop code is not executed?

Comment: Hmm, all I see is JavaScript does not understand property `input`. Try to change `options.inputs = []` to `optionInputs = []` . Hope this will help!

Comment: sir i tried but got error Cannot find name 'optionInputs'. ?

Comment: Did you declare `optionInputs` inside the function? If so, then declare `public optionInputs = []` above the constructor.

Comment: sir after declare optionInputs  again got same error?

Comment: please update this.subCategoryObject value which was show in console log

Comment: @Utpaul why we need to update here my scenario is different ?

Comment: @kapilsoni because of this.subCategoryObject have expected value or not

Comment: sir i got error in the first line after iterate loop value is not push in the array so value is not print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this would be by using the `addInput(...)` method from the `Alert` instance to add the inputs:

> ```
> addInput(input: AlertInputOptions): Alert;
>
> export interface AlertInputOptions {
>     type?: string;
>     name?: string | number;
>     placeholder?: string;
>     value?: string;
>     label?: string;
>     checked?: boolean;
>     disabled?: boolean;
>     id?: string;
>     handler?: Function;
>     min?: string | number;
>     max?: string | number;
> }
> ```

So using your code it'd look like this:

```
import { AlertController, Alert, ... } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...

public showAlert(): Promise<any> {

     // Create the alert with no options
     let alert: Alert = this.alertCtrl.create({});

      // Here we will generate dynamically check-box
      for(let i=0; i< data.subCategoriesDtos.length; i++) {
        this.subCategoryObject  = data.subCategoriesDtos[i];

        alert.addInput({
            value: this.subCategoryObject.keyId,
            label: this.subCategoryObject.subCategoryName,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: this.showSelectedSubcategory(this.selectedSubcategoryArray[i])
        });
      }

      return alert.present();
}
```

Comment: sir how to use this in our class actually i m new in ionic?

Comment: The first part of the answer is just information. So just copy the content of the `showAlert()` method to your own code, and should work as it is (please also remember to add `Alert` in the imports at the top of the page). @kapilsoni

Comment: Glad to hear that @kapilsoni :)

Comment: Sir plz can you tell m how this error is removed  after import Alert ?

Comment: Of course @kapilsoni. This line `let alert: Alert = this.alertCtrl.create({});` defines the property `alert` as of type `Alert`, so that's why you need to import `Alert`; otherwise Typescript will show an error since it does not know what `Alert` is and where to find it.